# Encountering this error: Error In Script -2147023706 When Executing VB Script

Tags: windows, vbscript, scripting

I am encountering an unknown error when executing successive VB script files.

Most of the time, these VB scripts work without any issue. But then from time to time, I encounter the following error message.

> Error In Script - -2147023706

I have tried to capture the description of the error but when I try to output the error in a message box, it comes out as blank.

I do not believe it's an issue in the scripts since they work without issue when executed alone. And the error seems to occur sporadically; from time to time. I am wondering if it's because Windows is executing another process which may be interfering with the execution of the script etc.

I would like to know if someone has encountered this scenario before and some information on what could be causing this. And perhaps a way to resolve it. But for now I am unable to identify what could be causing this error.

Comment: Has anyone encountered issues when executing successive VB scripts? Are there any performance considerations for this?

Comment: Without seeing your code there's nothing we could do to help.

Comment: Show use your code, so we can reproduce this error. :-)

Comment: This looks like a COM Automation error, do you use Internet Explorer Object Model somewhere in your script? Or any other automation? How does the error message appear? Only this number appears without any additional information (...VBScript runtime error etc.) ?

Comment: Yes, it's a vb script run time error. And I am calling both IE objects in my script.